# Is there an Oracle analytic function to help compute max value between billing days?

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

### Problem:

I would like to have help adding a **PERIOD_MAX** column, which calculates the maximum DAILY_USAGE value between billing periods.  Is there an [Oracle Analytic Function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407) to help me here?

NOTE: The new PERIOD_MAX column should indicate 'Y' when the row equals the maximum of the DAILY_USAGE value within all the rows since the previous billing day (in the black-bordered boxes, which are partitioned by the BILLING_DAY).

### How I want it to look:

[image: Figure 1]

### Here is a description of each column:

- **READ_TIME**: The time of the daily meter read each morning
- **BILLING_DAY**: A separator indicating the end of a billing cycle; we bill the customer on this day.  Since the number of records is arbitrary, we may or may not get a BILLING_DAY='Y' to begin each week.  *(This is why the 21st row was intentionally excluded.)*
- **METER_READING**: The reading on the face of the meter.  It cumulatively counts upward.
- **DAILY_USAGE**: The amount of energy consumed since the previous read.
- **PERIOD_MAX**: A column I need to help me highlight the **peak read** within each billing period.

### Here is an Oracle query:

Please start with this query, which generates data like it exists in my database, and try to add the desired PERIOD_MAX column.

```
  SELECT READ_TIME, BILLING_DAY, SUM (DAILY_USAGE) OVER (ORDER BY READ_TIME) + 1000 AS METER_READING, DAILY_USAGE
FROM (SELECT X.SEQ + TRUNC (SYSDATE - 20) + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE / 8 + 0.3         AS READ_TIME
           , CASE WHEN X.SEQ / 7 = TRUNC (X.SEQ / 7) THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END     AS BILLING_DAY
           , ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE * 100, 2)                                 AS DAILY_USAGE
        FROM ( SELECT LEVEL AS SEQ FROM DUAL
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20) X) Y ORDER BY READ_TIME;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cumulative sum (or really count) of `billing_day` to generate a group.  Then, do a max within the group:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by period order by daily_usage desc) = 1
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as period_max
from (select t.*,
             count(billing_day) over (order by reading_day) as period
      from t
     ) t;
```